# Extract rows from specific date (time conversion)

Tags: oracle, datetime, time, oracle11g

I have column contains dates as below:

**'03-DEC-15 08.27.26.869000000 AM';**

I'm try to get all rows from 03-DEC-15.
When I did :

```
select * from tableX where colT = '03-DEC-15'; 
--or
select * from tableX where colT = TO_TIMESTAMP ('03-DEC-15','dd-mon-rr');
--or
select * from tableX where colT = to_date('03-DEC-15','dd-mon-rr');
```

I got zero rows.

Comment: You have a timestamp with a time portion. If you don't specify a time portion in your TO_DATE, TO_TIMESTAMP it will default to midnight. So unless you have dates in your table like '03-DEC-15 00.00.00.000000000 AM' you wont get any matches. You need to TRUNC colt to do the comparison.

Comment: I tried to: TRUNC(colT ,'DD-MOM-YY')  but it's wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @BriteSponge mentioned, your column values have times other than midnight, so comparing them with a variable that is at exactly midnight is not expected to find a match.

You can either ignore the time portion of the column values by [truncating them](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions236.htm#SQLRF06151):

```
select * from tableX where trunc(colT) = date '2015-12-03';
```

which would prevent any index on that column being used, or preferably use a range for the right-hand side of the comparison:

```
select * from tableX
where colT >= timestamp '2015-12-03 00:00:00'
and colT < timestamp '2015-12-04 00:00:00';
```

(You could use `between` but as that is inclusive you risk missing or double-counting data, so I find this explicitly syntax clearer and less ambiguous. I've also used [datetime literals](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062) instead of `to_date()` to avoid ambiguity; you're using 2-digit years and NLS-sensitive month abbreviations, which could cause you problems at some point).